# Dynamic loading of javascript bypassing twig cache

Tags: caching

I am trying to figure out the correct way to have a javascript library dynamically loaded with every page load. For example, consider the scenario where I want to let the user toggle whether or not they want a 3rd party JS library to be loaded on the site.

The issue I am having is that I cannot use hook_page_attachments_alter because once the page is rendered, the result is cached. If the conditional changes (the user toggles), the hook_page_attachments_alter doesn't run again for the page until the cache is cleared.

What I want is a script that runs on every page load to calculate whether or not the 3rd party library should be included, eg:

```
if ($some_user_toggle) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_custom_js';
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers or an example of how to do this please!
Thanks!

Comment: GDPR modules offer similar functionalities. They can be used to conditionally load cookies, but they also offer conditional loading of Social media widgets. Take a look at the Cookies module https://www.drupal.org/project/cookies

Comment: What cacheability metadata have you added to the page in the hook? As a reminder: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-api

Comment: @Hudri, that is a great example. It is exactly the functionality that I was thinking of. However, I am looking through the code and cannot see / find the mechanism that it is using. I am sure I will find it if I keep looking, but if you have any hints, that would be great to save me time!

Comment: @cilefen, I had considered using tags, but I couldn't think how to make it work. Any more guidance would be very much appreciated.